# Subalgebras of the Real Octonions under Multiplication

Tags: octonions, nonassociative-algebras

I am interested to know what the subalgebras of the octonions look like. I tried searching for it but to no avail. What did show up was "[Subalgebras of the Split Octonions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00006-018-0859-6)," which was quite nice. Yet, I am still trying to understand the subalgebras of the octonions. Do we have a classification of the subalgebras of the real octonions under multiplication?

We know that [the octonions form an alternative algebra under multiplication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.09412.pdf), hence the subalgebras generated by one or two elements are associative, but not necessarily so with three elements. I would also appreciate if there's more we could say about some special, easy to generate subalgebras of the real octonions, something along the lines of this question: [Do the octonions contain infinitely many copies of the quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096742/do-the-octonions-contain-infinitely-many-copies-of-the-quaternions)

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Properties).

Comment: What's wrong with the last link? The question and answer effectively mention where all possible proper real subalgebras of $\mathbb{O}$ come from - they're all complex and quaternionic.

Comment: @runway44 Do you mean "Do the octonions contain infinitely many copies of the quaternions?" There, the last answer only says what the subalgebras generated by one or two elements look like. It does not say what all the subalgebras look like. The subalgebras seem to be more than just those given there (see Maximal subalgebras of the octonions by Stephen M. Gagola III).

Comment: @BenjaminT That paper is talking about octonion algebras over arbitrary fields. The case of real octonions is as I said: all subalgebras are complex or quaternionic. If you do the split octonions (again a nonassociative real algebra) there is a new 6D subalgebra called the sextonions.

Comment: @runway44 Oh I see. I didn't pay attention to it being over a general field. Yes, now that I think about it, I think I do see that they are complex or quaternionic. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, the real octonions are not associative under multiplication. Take three octonions that don't commute. The subalgebra generated is not associative, so it can't be complex nor quaternionic. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I was referring to proper subalgebras. If two octonions don't commute, they generate a quaternionic subalgebra. If a third octonion is not in the quaternionic subalgebra generated by the first two, then the three of them generate the entire algebra. (It is not sufficient for the third octonion to merely not commute with the first two - for instance $i,j,k$ don't commute but $k$ is generated by $i$ and $j$. But it is necessary and sufficient that the third octonion doesn't associate with the first two.)

Comment: @runway44 Thanks, I'm glad to hear that! Im still not quite sure why when generated by three nonassociative elements the algebra is the entire set? Does this follow from the octonions being the smallest algebra with the nonassociative property? And when we speak of a subalgebra we don't need it to contain any special element such as the identity, only that it is closed under multiplication, right? Do I read under composition algebras to learn all these? Thanks!

Comment: That three nonassociating elements generates all of $\Bbb O$ can be proved different ways. The best, I think, would be to start investigating arbitrary real normed division algebras by deducing facts about the induced inner product. Once you have that the adjoint of multiplying by an octonion is multiplying by its conjugate, it follows that if $H$ is a quaternionic subalgebra and $\ell\not\in H$, then you can project $\ell$ onto $H^{\perp}$, and then $\langle a,b\ell\rangle=\langle \overline{b}a,\ell\rangle=0$ so $H\perp H\ell$ is orthogonal, hence $H\oplus H\ell$ is direct, and dimension $8$.

Comment: By subalgebra I mean unital subalgebra, but it doesn't actually matter here; if you have a vector subspace closed under multiplication and it contains a nonreal element $x$, then it must contain $1$. (You can show $1$ will be in the span of $x$ and $x^2$ by splitting into cases; you might as well consider $x\in S^1\subset \Bbb C$ for simplicity.) Yes, I would read about real normed division algebras (and then segue to composition algebras if you wish, which can have split signature "norms").

Comment: Thanks @runway44! Lemme do a little more reading and research from your suggestions first!